# The definitions of terms in $P=CV^2f$

Tags: digital-circuits, power-consumption

My textbook gives the equation for the power dissipation
$$ P=CV^2 f $$
but after reading it a couple times, I can't get very clear on exactly what each of these is measuring.  It describes $P$ as the "power dissipation", which I take to mean something like the heat lost to the environment as the current passes through the circuit.  $C$ is the capacitance, and I take this to be a property of the materials that make up the circuit.

$V$ is the voltage, or potential difference -- but what is happening here?  For instance, suppose the computer is off, then I assume $V=0$.  Ok, now you turn your computer on, and the there is some charge flowing through the circuit.  But what is it doing?

My best guess is that one should imagine a transistor with nothing going on, no charge, and it is either in an open or closed state.  To get it to switch, you either have to apply a low charge or high charge, depending on the type of transistor.  When you apply it, though, if you now cut the power, would it store the state of the transistor?  Or do you have to maintain a voltage in order for the transistor to maintain its state?  If it's the latter then it doesn't sound like causing a switch requires applying a voltage, so much as just maintaining some state requires a voltage.

And am I correct in believing that $f$, the frequency of switching, is just the total number of times that a transistor anywhere in the circuit is made to switch per unit time?  So for instance, the reason why we don't call this, say, $n$ the number of transistors that switch, is because the same transistor may (or may not) switch repeatedly?  Sometimes descriptions of this part talk about the clock rate, and it almost sounds like they're saying that a single transistor switches back and forth with the alternating current applied to the circuit ... almost like it's just an electrical phenomenon not actually part of the computation?  I think that's almost certainly not what I'm supposed to be getting from these descriptions.  But I can't seem to get a description of exactly what is happening in the chip, which corresponds to what these variables measure.